# How to sensitively and insensitively case search on a field

Tags: elasticsearch

When I use filter lowercase like this, I can insensitively case search on foo field but, I can't sensitively case search on foo field.
In my case, I need to decide which to insensitively or sensitively case search on foo field depending on the situation.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "annotation_type": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "keyword"
          "normalizer": "lowercase_keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea would be to use two `keyword` fields, like this:

```
  "mappings": {
    "annotation_type": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "insensitive": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "lowercase_keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can use `foo` to search in a case-sensitive way and `foo.insensitive` to search case-insensitively.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This problem has been resolved by your good idea.